# ENV variables are nil in Production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I start rails server in Development mode, everything works fine.  But when I start rails server in Production mode all my ENV variables which I call like ENV[:blahblah] are nil.  blahblah exits in the application.yml.

I am using rbenv 0.4.0 and ruby 2.2.3

Thanks for the help

Comment: Wait, can we take a look at your application.yml?

Comment: Sorry, I meant in terms of your set up. You should be reading them from ENV vars, so your set up should look more like: development: blah: <%= ENV['SOMEENV'] %>. Not looking for your application's secrets :P, more to see if you're setting up the structure correctly.

Answer (score 0):

" "rails_env: production

# rails_env: development

# rails_env: test

had to remove that extra space in the beginning so: